# Segmentation Fault in my code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
main()
{
    struct passenger_node {
        char *name;
        struct passenger_node *next;
    };

    struct flight {
        char airline[MAXNAME];
        int number;
        struct passenger_node *passengers;
    };

    // New passengers are added to the front of the list of passengers.
    void add_passenger(char *name, struct flight *flp) {
          struct passenger_node n;
          n.name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
          strncpy(n.name, name, strlen(name)+1);
          n.next = flp->passengers;
    };

    void list_passengers(struct flight fl) {
        printf("%s", fl.passengers->name);
    }

    struct flight my_flight;
    strcpy(my_flight.airline, "Air");
    my_flight.number = 111;
    my_flight.passengers = NULL;
    add_passenger("MMM", &my_flight);
    list_passengers(my_flight);
}
```

I am getting a segmentation error for my line fl.passengers->name in the function list_passengers? Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Clearly the code you are posting is not the code you have on your pc. The presented code does not compile in a C compiler as C does not allow declaring functions within a function. Please post the code you are using.

Comment: @RedX: gcc does allow this nonstandard code: http://ideone.com/OEomZQ

Comment: @sharth Thanks for clarifying. Didn't know about this (IMHO horrible) gcc extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add_passenger` fails to update the `passengers` pointer:

```
void add_passenger(char *name, struct flight *flp) {
      struct passenger_node n;
      n.name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
      strncpy(n.name, name, strlen(name)+1);
      n.next = flp->passengers;
      flp->passengers = ???;                 //<--- UPDATE HERE
};
```

You're going to have to dynamically allocate `passenger_node` for this and can't use the local one.

```
void add_passenger(char *name, struct flight *flp) {
      struct passenger_node *np = malloc(sizeof(struct passenger_ndoe));
      if (!np) return;

      np->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
      strncpy(np->name, name, strlen(name)+1);
      np->next = flp->passengers;
      flp->passengers = np;
};
```

Your `list_passengers` is also incorrect. It only shows the first passenger and doesn't check for an empty passenger list:

```
void list_passengers(struct flight fl) {
    struct passenger_node *np;

    for ( np = fl.passengers; np != NULL; np = np->next )
        printf("%s\n", np->name);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is better to create a pointer to struct rather than the struct itself?

Comment: @Mat.S It's because the struct itself when declared inside a function exists only inside the function, when the function returns it will disappear (or rather not be valid to access). You don't want that.

Comment: @Mat.S You can't use the pointer to a local structure (on the stack) outside of the scope it's defined in. So if you take `&n` in your original code, you can't use it once outside of the `add_passenger` function.

Comment: If you don't use `malloc`, the `struct passenger_node n` will only exist as long as we are in the `add_passenger` function, whereas the `passenger_node` created with `malloc` will exist until it is freed or until the program exits.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `list_passengers()` to:

```
void list_passengers(struct flight fl) {
    assert(fl.passengers != NULL);
    printf("%s", fl.passengers->name);
}
```

You will see that `fl.passengers == NULL`, and you attempt to dereference it.

Comment: I have added a passenger MMM

Comment: `add_passenger()` has an empty function body, so it will do nothing.

Comment: Added the implementation

Comment: Please change your list_passengers() to what I suggested, and tell me if `fl.passengers` is still null. It will be.

Comment: You are right, I get demo: main.c:31: list_passengers: Assertion `fl.passengers != ((void *)0)' failed. How and where should I change my code then?

Comment: lurker has included in his answer an example of a correct version of `add_passenger()`.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need this (should compile with any C compiler):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNAME 100

struct passenger_node {
    char *name;
    struct passenger_node *next;
};

struct flight {
    char airline[MAXNAME];
    int number;
    struct passenger_node *passengers;
};


// New passengers are added to the front of the list of passengers.
void add_passenger(char *name, struct flight *flp) {
      struct passenger_node *newpassenger ;
      newpassenger = malloc(sizeof (struct passenger_node));
      newpassenger->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
      strncpy(newpassenger->name, name, strlen(name)+1);
      newpassenger->next = flp->passengers;
      flp->passengers = newpassenger;
};

void list_passengers(struct flight fl) {
    printf("%s", fl.passengers->name);
}

main()
{
    struct flight my_flight;
    strcpy(my_flight.airline, "Air");
    my_flight.number = 111;
    my_flight.passengers = NULL;
    add_passenger("MMM", &my_flight);
    add_passenger("XXX", &my_flight);
    list_passengers(my_flight);
}
```

But you still need to make the `list_passengers` function work. For the moment only the first passenger in the list is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions are not allowed in C. you have defined functions inside main which is a function.
And `name` is a pointer and you dint allocate memory to it. allocate menmory then access it and make sure that you don't access NULL pointers. This is results in segmentation fault .